# How to handle missing values in the test dataset?

Tags: r, missing-data, mice

I have a training and a test dataset and both presents some missing data. I used the MICE R package to handle the missing values in training dataset and now I'm wondering how to handle them in the test data.

I have two options:

1 - I can merge both the training and the test dataset and apply MICE function in this new dataset to replace all missing values; or

2 - I can apply MICE in the training data and in the test data, separately.

Which option is better and why?

If I merge the datasets then the predicted values for the missing data will be biased by the test dataset.

But If I don't merge them the predicted missing values for the training dataset will be biased by the training data and the predicted missing values for the test dataset will be biased by test data, right?

I'm quite new to the MICE R package and handling missing values in data.

Comment: Imagine all you had was the training data and you built your model.  Then in the future you got the test data without the variable you were trying to predict, so you apply your existing model and made predictions for the test data; here it might make sense to handle missing values for the rest of the test data being used as an input to the model, presumably in the same way as you did for the training data.  Finally you compare those predictions with the actual values for the variable in the test data; here it might not make sense to be comparing with missing values as your test.

Comment: So building your model, you should use the training data alone - this is a key method to avoid the test data contaminating the model.  For the input values of the test data, you might combine the training and test data to handle missing values - it depends on the context

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Henry. You said that I need to merge the training and test data to handle missing values but it depends on the context. Can you further explain this? How can one know if they need or not to combine the datasets to handle missing values?